C:\FATIH\angular_text>npm i -g @angular/cli@14.2.5 npm error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')
C:\FATIH\angular_text>npm i -g @angular/cli@14.2.5
npm error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\FATİH\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-04T22_46_12_043Z-debug-0.log

I deleted node.js and installed it, it did not change
Installing packages and seeing the packages I installed in the npm list

See npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut'), specifically this answer. Node.js cannot handle the İ character in your directory name
